# Enable to send mail with amazon-ses

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, php-7, amazon-ses

I am tring to send email from amazon server with [codeigniter-amazon-ses](https://github.com/joelcox/codeigniter-amazon-ses) library.

Error I am facing is  recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream.